Can i update multiple views asynchronously of a layout in android kotlin?
I have a project, in which , we have drawer layout and recyclerview.
on drawer menu item click, i want to change fragment/ submit a new list data to recyclerview, so i called drawer.closeDrawrr()
adapter.submitlist(list) (adapter uses DiffUtil) ,
but i saw drawer stops at any point during closing, so i want drawer close smoothly, without stopping for a ms, and asynchronously list should also be changed
I tried multiple things, but not getting desired result,
I found Asynlayoutinflater(but in my project we have inflated fragment, which is not allowed in it), but not getting solution for view

Seems like you're making an assumption about what is slowing down your app. Profile your code, identify the bottleneck, then optimize.

There must be a UI blocking operation in your code, usually, it should close smoothly. Could you please share a code snippet so that I can help you?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
